# How to Read specification in elixir

Tags: elixir, heap

What dose this mean or how to think/implement it ?

```
• @spec add(heap(), integer()) :: heap()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the function add/2 that adds an integer to a heap. 
The function `add` is to take two parameter the first being the `heap` and the second the `integer`. 
It is to return a new `heap` which will be the initial heap with the integer added.
All those brackets are just part of the elixir syntax.

Comment: Thank you i have other question, what is the difference between specification and type definition like the following:  @type tree :: {:node, integer(), tree(), tree()} | nil

Comment: `@type tree :: {:node, integer(), tree(), tree()} | nil ` say that a `tree` is to a have a type structure labelled `:node` that contains an integer and two other trees (I guess the left and right branches). Or else it can simply be `nil`  - that is an empty tree.

Comment: Can we rewrite it as:

DefModule Example

defstruct value: val, left: l, right: r

and accept it as argument in a method as:
def whatever`( tree = %{Example{value:...}) do...end`

Does it return "nil", e.g empty tree, or does not matter what it returns?